# PHP rearrange the data based on id

Tags: php, laravel

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [member_id] => 8
            [total] => 5
            [mainroomid] => 2         
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [member_id] => 11
            [total] => 2
            [mainroomid] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [member_id] => 8
            [total] => 8
            [mainroomid] => 2

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [member_id] => 11
            [total] => 3
            [mainroomid] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [member_id] => 29
            [total] => 4
            [mainroomid] => 2

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [member_id] => 8
            [total] => 5
            [mainroomid] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [member_id] => 11
            [total] => 3
            [mainroomid] => 1
        )
)
```

The above data is returned from the MySQL database, my logic get stuck here which is I want to loop the data accordingly and rearrange the data into a new array. Does it mean that all the same member id I need to sum up all the total and separate based on the mainroomid. Anyone can help with this ya :(? Below is the data that I need to show.

Final data

```
[0] => Array

    (
      [0] => Array(

               [member_id] => 8
               [total] => 13
               [mainroomid] => 2 
            )

      [1] => Array(

               [member_id] => 11
               [total] => 5
               [mainroomid] => 2 
            )

      [2] => Array(

             [member_id] => 29
             [total] => 4
             [mainroomid] => 2 
          )
     )

[1] => Array

    (
      [0] => Array(

               [member_id] => 8
               [total] => 5
               [mainroomid] => 1 
            )

      [1] => Array(

               [member_id] => 11
               [total] => 3
               [mainroomid] => 1
            )
     )
```

Comment: just use group by (mainroomid, member_id) in your mysql query and get the sum for total

Comment: Share your controller method piece of code to modify on

Comment: try array_column($arr, null, 'mainroomid')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with laravel's collections by using the [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby)
and [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby) method.

```
// Lets say $data contains the data you listed above.

$sorted = collect($data)->sortBy('member_id')->groupBy('mainroomid')->values()->toArray();
```